# Statsmodels returns NaN for model.params

Tags: python, glm, statsmodels

I've fit a GLM model using statsmodels, and if I run fitted_model.summary(), I can see my coefficients.

However, when I run fitted_model.params, I get NaN for all coefficients except the intercept (the intercept appears as it does in the summary).  Any idea how to isolate and return these coefficients??

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

def run_glm(self, df, independent_vars, dependent_var, offset, exposure, tweedie_power = 1.1):
    """
    Creates and runs a generalized linear model (GLM) using a Tweedie distribution.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df (dataframe) - modeling data
    independent_var (list of strings) - columns in dataframe with independent variables
    dependent_var (string) - column in dataframe with dependent variable
    offset (string) - column in dataframe with offset data
    exposure (string) - column in dataframe with exposure data
    tweedie_power (float) - Tweedie distribution power

    Returns
    -------
    (model) - fit GLM model
    """

    #Define dependent variable
    Y_var = df[dependent_var]

    #Add column of 1's as intercept to independent variable dataframe
    X_vars = sm.add_constant(df[independent_vars].copy(), prepend=False)

    model = sm.GLM(endog = Y_var, 
                  exog = X_vars, 
                  family = sm.families.Tweedie(link = sm.families.links.log,
                                               var_power = tweedie_power, 
                                               link_power = 0),
                  offset = df[offset], 
                  exposure = df[exposure])

    return model.fit()


model_glm = run_glm(train, dependent_var='pp', independent_vars=['group1', 'group2', 'group3'], offset='log_balanced_aa', exposure ='exposure_aa')

model_glm.summary()

Generalized Linear Model Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  pp  No. Observations:   33430           
Model:  GLM Df Residuals:   33426           
Model Family:   Tweedie Df Model:   3           
Link Function:  log Scale:  107836.486          
Method: IRLS    Log-Likelihood: nan         
Date:   Thu, 28 Dec 2017    Deviance:   4.29E+07            
Time:   10:06:06    Pearson chi2:   3.60E+09            
No. Iterations: 11                  

        coef    std err z       P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
group1  0.0725  0.059   1.219   0.223   -0.044  0.189
group2  0.1464  0.123   1.191   0.233   -0.094  0.387
group3  0.0377  0.1     0.378   0.705   -0.158  0.233
const   -0.3894 0.613   -0.636  0.525   -1.59   0.811


model_glm.params

group1           NaN
group2           NaN
group3           NaN
const            -0.389427
```

Comment: As clever as some of us are, I think we'd need to see the code you've run and at least a sample of the data.

Comment: You can check `model_glm._results.params` which is the numpy array before it is wrapped into a pandas Series. A reproducible example is necessary. I don't see either what might be wrong in this example.